# What is the difference between c=a,b and c=(a,b)?

Tags: c

What is the difference between the 4th and 5th lines?

```
int main() 
{
    int a = 3, b = 5, c, d; 
    c = a, b; 
    d = (a, b); 
    printf("c=%d d=%d", c, d); 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c=3 d=5
```

Comment: The comma operator `,` has lower precedence than assignment `=`, meaning the first statement is parsed as `(c = a), b;`.

Comment: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) will also help.